# Calculate thermal expansion from Helmholtz free energy

Tags: thermodynamics

Is there a way to calculate the coefficient of thermal expansion ($\alpha$) from Helmholtz free energy (A) ?

I use the definition $\alpha = \frac{1}{V}(\frac{\partial V}{ \partial T})_p$. 
With Maxwell relations, thermal expansion can be written as a function of Gibbs free energy (G) . 
$\alpha = \frac{1}{V} \frac{\partial^{2}  G}{\partial T \partial p}$

I want to calculate the coefficient of thermal expansion from Helmholtz free energy.
What i tried: 
$G(P) = A(V(P)) + P  V(P)$

$\frac{\partial G}{\partial p} = \frac{\partial A}{\partial V}\frac{\partial V}{\partial p} + V + p \frac{\partial V}{\partial p} $

With $\frac{\partial A}{\partial V} = -p$

$\frac{\partial  G}{\partial p} = - p \frac{\partial V}{\partial p} + V -  p \frac{\partial V}{\partial p} = V$

$\frac{1}{V}\frac{\partial^{2}  G}{\partial T \partial p} = \frac{1}{V} \frac{\partial V}{\partial T}$

I could show the relation, but the term with A was cancelled. Is there a way to calculate $\alpha$ directly from A ?

Thanks in advance,

-Edit:
Did i find another way?

Maxwell relations:
$(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_p = -(\frac{\partial S}{\partial p})_T$ and $-S = (\frac{\partial A}{\partial T})_V$

$(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_p =\frac{\partial}{\partial p} (\frac{\partial   A}{\partial T})_V)_T = \frac{\partial}{\partial T} (\frac{\partial   A}{\partial V}\frac{\partial V}{\partial p}) $

Or did I miss something ?

Answer (score 1):

Kind of, in differential form we have:
$$dA=-SdT-pdV$$
If we Sub in:
$$dV=(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_p dT+(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p})_T dp$$
We get: 
$$dA=-SdT-p[(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_p dT+(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p})_T dp]$$
So
$$(\frac{\partial A}{\partial T})_p=-S-p (\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_p$$
So:
$$\frac{1}{V}(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_p=-\frac{1}{pV}[S+(\frac{\partial A}{\partial T})_p]$$